# Excel VBA - Copying specific columns from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code that I have, but something seems to be incorrect,
Only the first row of data seems to pop up in the second worksheet.

```
Sub copycolumns()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
        erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow, 1)

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow, 2)

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow, 3)
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
End Sub
```

Editing my previous code.

I found a code more efficient than my previous code,

```
Sub CopyPastingColumns()

    Dim erow As Long

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I6").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)

End Sub
```

---

How to concatenate two rows from sheet 1 and paste it in any column in Sheet 2?

For example, both the columns are numbers,

In Sheet1,
column A has 123456, column B has 1

I want output on Sheet2 column C as 1234561

Comment: Although it is not the best practice, I'd suggest trying `lastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to concatenate column 3 and column 4 from worksheet 1 and paste it in 5th column of worksheet 2? Both column 3 and column 4 are numerical values. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copycolumns()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 2).Copy Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy Sheet2.Cells(erow, 3)
        'Edit: added line below
        Sheet2.Cells(erow, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & _
                                      Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        erow = erow + 1
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to concatenate column 3 and column 4 from worksheet 1 and paste it in 5th column of worksheet 2? Both column 3 and column 4 are numerical values. Please help me out!

Comment: Hello sir !! thanks a lot for your response!! Really appreciate it. I've edited my question, please have a look at it and give a solution for it if possible. Thanks once again!!!

Comment: If you have new code it's best to create a new question.

Comment: Sure, created a new question,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084684/copy-pasting-columns-from-sheet-1-to-sheet-2-but-concatenating-is-needed