# Copy pasting columns from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, but concatenating is needed

Tags: vba, excel

This is the VBA code that I have, to copy columns from sheet1 to sheet2.

How to concatenate two rows from sheet 1 and paste it in any column in Sheet 2?

For example, both the columns are numbers,

In Sheet1, 
column A has 123456, column B has 1

I want output on Sheet2 column C as 1234561

Please help, thanks!!

```
Sub CopyPastingColumns()

Dim erow As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Select

        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I6").Select

        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you may be trying to only concatenate and copy a single entry at a time.  So, here's another approach that appends the last entry from Sheet1 (same row, two columns) to a list on Sheet2:

```
Sub CopyPastingColumns()

        Dim wksht As Worksheet
        Set wksht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        wksht.Activate

        wksht.Range("A1").Select 'your D6
        Dim rgLHS As Range
        Set rgLHS = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))


        wksht.Range("B1").Select 'your I6
        Dim rgRHS As Range
        Set rgRHS = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

        Dim erow As Long
        erow = rgLHS.Rows.Count


        Set rgLHS = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow, rgLHS.Column)
        Set rgRHS = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow, rgRHS.Column)

        Set wksht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        wksht.Activate
        wksht.Range("C1").Select
        Dim rgC As Range
        Set rgC = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

        Dim resultErow As Long
        resultErow = rgC.Rows.Count + 1
        Set rgC = wksht.Cells(resultErow, rgC.Column)

        rgC.Value = rgLHS.Value & rgRHS.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  If the code answers your question, an upvote would be much appreciated as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
 Dim rg As Range

For Each rg In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows

    rg.Cells(1, 3) = rg.Cells(1, 1) & rg.Cells(1, 2)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think working with the 'Selection' may get in the way.  Just work with the ranges.  The code below assumes your two input ranges/selections are the same size.

```
Sub CopyPastingColumns()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

        Dim rgLHS As Range
        Set rgLHS = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select

        Dim rgRHS As Range
        Set rgRHS = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

        Dim result As Variant
        ReDim result(1 To rgRHS.Rows.Count)
        Dim rowIdx As Integer
        For rowIdx = 1 To rgRHS.Rows.Count
            result(rowIdx) = rgLHS.Cells(rowIdx, 1) & rgRHS.Cells(rowIdx, 1)
        Next rowIdx

        Dim rgC As Range
        Dim wksht As Worksheet
        Set wksht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set rgC = wksht.Range("C1")
        Set rgC = rgC.Resize(UBound(result), 1)
        rgC.Value = Application.Transpose(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited the original answer to load/copy a range of cells.